# Javascript Prototype Design Pattern return statement

Tags: javascript, prototype-pattern

Currently have been refactoring an app, partially written in *.js. After consideration have decided to use the Revealing Prototype Design Pattern which lets to encapsulate states as well as reveal states you want to expose. 
Let's say my code is:

```
'use strict';
var Api = function(){ };
Api.prototype = funcion(){
 let 
   getName = function(name) {
      return name;          
 },
  ...
   200 methods more 
  ...

return {
  getName: getName,
  ...
  return 150 methods more
  ...
 }
}();
```

Code is correct and all works as intended, but the return statement looks a bit sloppy. Can I return all the public methods in a more concise way?

Comment: No, there is no way to refer to a scope as a sort of object. You could just create the functions as part of the object initializer.

Comment: If those are all going to be "public" methods of your Api object, you could just define each of those methods in your main function block as `this.func = function(){};`